# weird R issue with table()

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 503 obs x 637 vars I'm trying to coerce into a frequency table. My list is of the form shown below, where blanks are NAs, but is spread out over very many more columns and rows

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | string |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | sting_2 |  |
|  | string_2 | string_3 |  |  |

When I run table(list), though, I get a super weird output and can only really screenshot it to show [image: Super wierd table() output!]

This doesnt happen on the dataframe I use to generate this list, and I can't seem to figure out or search a way around it. Additionally, when I try to use `table()` on just one column in my list, as in `table(list[2])`,I get `NULL` even though I'd expect `string 1 string_2 1`. Very unsure what's happening, and swear I had it working before in both cases. Please help!!!!

Comment: You have a `list` or a `data.frame`? Sometimes the data as presented on the console is ambiguous from what is shown in stackoverflow, can you add the output from `dput(x[1:10,1:10])`?

Comment: @r2evans its a list, but the same thing happens when i make it as.data.frame. did you mean running ```dput(table(list)[1:10,1:10])```? that returns "incorrect number of dimensions". running the code the way you wrote it returns 'object x not found'

Comment: `table(list(1:5))` gives a 1d table; `table(list(1:5,2:6,3:7))` gives a 3d array of counts. If your `list` is length 637, then you are producing a heckuva large-dimension table. I have no idea what use that would be (I don't know your context), but that seems impossible difficult to evaluate on a console. Given my second example, what output are you expecting to get? Perhaps it would help to see the output from `dput(lapply(x[1:3],head))`, and what you expect `table(.)` of that to produce.

Comment: I get that, but I guess what makes me doubly confused is the fact that ```table(list[2]))``` returns ```NA```

Comment: You know, that's a great question. If you want to share some of your data, perhaps somebody can help you. As it stands, the sample data in your question is not representative of your real list of vectors, so there's really very little we can do to help.

Comment: try `table(unlist(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `table` on a `list` (as you described in the comments of your question) produces one dimension for every vector/element within the list. For example,

```r
table(list(c(1,1,2)))
# 1 2 
# 2 1 

x <- list(c(1,1,2),c(1,1,2),c(1,1,2))
table(x)
# , , x.3 = 1
#    x.2
# x.1 1 2
#   1 2 0
#   2 0 0
# , , x.3 = 2
#    x.2
# x.1 1 2
#   1 0 0
#   2 0 1
```

The first (1d) list produces a 1d table; the second (3d) list produces a 3d table array. So your data 637 vars (I'm inferring each element within the list is a var), you will get a 637-dim return.

If you want a table of the contents, then you need to unlist it.

```r
table(unlist(x))
# 1 2 
# 6 3
```

As to why you're getting `NULL`, it seems likely that you have all `NA` in that element. For example,

```r
table(c(x, list(c(NA,NA,NA))))
# < table of extent 2 x 2 x 2 x 0 >
```

(where we previously saw a 3-d table here). You can try to work around this with `useNA="always"` or `useNA="ifany"`.

```r
table(c(x, list(c(NA,NA,NA))), useNA="always")
# , , .3 = 1, .4 = NA
#       .2
# .1     1 2 <NA>
#   1    2 0    0
#   2    0 0    0
#   <NA> 0 0    0
# , , .3 = 2, .4 = NA
#       .2
# .1     1 2 <NA>
#   1    0 0    0
#   2    0 1    0
#   <NA> 0 0    0
# , , .3 = NA, .4 = NA
#       .2
# .1     1 2 <NA>
#   1    0 0    0
#   2    0 0    0
#   <NA> 0 0    0
```

which returns us closer to the "normal" output of your initial `table(x)`, or

```r
table(unlist(c(x, list(c(NA,NA,NA)))), useNA="always")
#    1    2 <NA> 
#    6    3    3
```

in a simplified view.

Comment: saved the day in the comments and as this response! thank you!!!!!